# Web fonts don't show some characters in Chrome for Windows

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, webfonts

I tried show ,  and  with Roboto and Open Sans:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Open+Sans&subset=greek-ext,latin,greek,vietnamese,cyrillic,latin-ext,cyrillic-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style type="text/css">
    .opensans {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    .roboto {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="roboto">
        <p>U+10320: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10321: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10322: <span></span></p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="opensans">
        <p>U+10320: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10321: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10322: <span></span></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But not work in *Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80* for *Windows 8.1*:

[image: old chars]

> - Note: I added Latin, Latin extended, Greek and Greek-extened.
> - Note: Work fine in Firefox.

Comment: Looks OK in my browsers, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, & Safari.

Comment: What versions of Chrome + Windows?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I think I found the reason, do not know if it's the most correct solution, but it seems to work fine http://stackoverflow.com/a/33727617/1518921

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox work because by default is used *Segoe UI Symbol* as *"replacement font"*

I modified code for:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol', sans-serif;
}
.opensans {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI Symbol', sans-serif;
}
.roboto {
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Segoe UI Symbol', sans-serif;
}
```

And work in Google Chrome.

See example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Roboto|Open+Sans&subset=greek-ext,latin,greek,vietnamese,cyrillic,latin-ext,cyrillic-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif, 'Segoe UI Symbol';
    }
    .abrilfatface {
        font-family: 'Abril Fatface', 'Segoe UI Symbol', sans-serif;
    }
    .roboto {
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'Segoe UI Symbol', sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="roboto">
        <p>Hello word! Foo “ ” – — … ‐ ‒ ° © ® ™ • ½ ¼ ¾ ⅓ ⅔ † ‡ µ ¢ £ € « » ♥ ¿ ? #</p>
        <p>U+10320: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10321: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10322: <span></span></p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="opensans">
        <p>Hello word! Foo “ ” – — … ‐ ‒ ° © ® ™ • ½ ¼ ¾ ⅓ ⅔ † ‡ µ ¢ £ € « » ♥ ¿ ? #</p>
        <p>U+10320: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10321: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10322: <span></span></p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="abrilfatface">
        <p>Hello word! Foo “ ” – — … ‐ ‒ ° © ® ™ • ½ ¼ ¾ ⅓ ⅔ † ‡ µ ¢ £ € « » ♥ ¿ ? #</p>
        <p>U+10320: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10321: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10322: <span></span></p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <p>Hello word! Foo “ ” – — … ‐ ‒ ° © ® ™ • ½ ¼ ¾ ⅓ ⅔ † ‡ µ ¢ £ € « » ♥ ¿ ? #</p>
        <p>U+10320: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10321: <span></span></p>
        <p>U+10322: <span></span></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```